# What happens when a point mass reached Centre of Gravity of another body?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

Suppose a body is slowly descending in a downwards firing rocket, in a tunnel dug through Earth's surface, and switches off the rocket just as it reaches earth's COG. Now since the body reached the Earth's COG with 0 velocity, according to me it would remain suspended there with the COG and body locally becoming inertial (I'm assuming the body is a point mass else the tidal force would rip it apart). Is this what actually would happen?

Comment: The tidal force at the center would not be strong at all. Assuming a spherical and *spherically symmetric* Earth, $g=\frac{4}{3}\pi \rho r$, where $\rho$ is the mass density around the center and $r$ is the distance from the center.

Comment: Simply switching off the rocket would not cause it to have zero velocity at the Earth's center.

Comment: Why do you think it might do anything different?